# CSS FlexBox recursive pattern align two items with different width in an row recursively

Tags: html, css, flexbox

```
<div class="main">
    <div class="1">Div 1</div>
    <div class="2">Div 2</div>

    <div class="1">Div 1</div>
    <div class="2">Div 2</div>

    <div class="1">Div 1</div>
    <div class="2">Div 2</div>

    <div class="1">Div 1</div>
    <div class="2">Div 2</div>

    <div class="1">Div 1</div>
    <div class="2">Div 2</div>

    <div class="1">Div 1</div>
    <div class="2">Div 2</div>

    <div class="1">Div 1</div>
    <div class="2">Div 2</div>
</div>
```

https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

If there would have been only one set of:

```
<div class="1">Div 1</div>
<div class="2">Div 2</div>
```

I would have organized class1, class 2 in one row, But here there is recurring such order.

What I am trying to achieve is that Possible with flex.

Analogy in real world situation=
`class="1"` will be label element and
`class="2"` will be input tag/element inside a form.

`class="1" and class="2"` even when in one row will have different width.

Current HTML is a metamorphic reproduction of some situations final goal will be to achieve such arrangement:

[image: desired layout]

[image: desired layout with notes]

Comment: Do you want output as shown in the image? Using flexbox

Comment: Yes, but currently we have to deal with the current HTML, which is a metamorphic of some real-world problem.

Comment: https://codepen.io/emmeiWhite/pen/eYdyQpK try this

Comment: Did you tried my updated answer... You will not have to change any HTML.. And CSS-Grids does have Browser Support like flexbox :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE:**

Using CSS-Grids we can achieve this without using extra wrapper.

**Codepen Link:** https://codepen.io/emmeiWhite/pen/eYdyQpK

```css
.main{
  width:500px;
  border:1px solid #ccc;
  padding:1rem;
   display:grid;
  grid-template-columns:1fr 4fr;
  grid-auto-rows:minmax(20px,auto)
}

.two{
  border:1px solid #ccc;
  margin-bottom:0.5rem;
}
```

```html
   <!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="main">
    <div class="one">Div 1</div>
    <div class="two">Div 2</div>
    <div class="one">Div 1</div>
    <div class="two">Div 2</div>
    <div class="one">Div 1</div>
    <div class="two">Div 2</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: w/o introduction of one more div for each set not possible?

Comment: do you mean the outer wrapper div? Yes possible but with CSS-Grid. Let me update

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_fieldset → This is also Good, but then input box is not aligned. You see.

Comment: Can we work around with flexbox there to align them in sobriety? In row they are already arranged.

Comment: Check the final result using CSS-Grids.. That is pretty simple as well

Answer (score -1):

Simply

1. wrap all class="1" elemnts in one div and
2. set it to flex direction-colum.
3. do the same to all class="2" elemnts
4. Wrap these 2 parents in a flex-direction row container.

   ```
   <div class="main">
     <div>
       <div class="1">Div 1</div>
       <div class="1">Div 1</div>
       <div class="1">Div 1</div>
   </div>
   <div>
     <div class="2">Div 2</div>
     <div class="2">Div 2</div>
     <div class="2">Div 2</div>
   </div>
   ```